# Why averaging stochastic gradient descent not always used?

Tags: neural-networks, gradient-descent

In some references [equation (20)](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) people tend to average or normalize the back propagated error by the number of examples in the mini-batch before updating the weights. while in other references is not the case.

I never averaged this error. Is there any explanation why it is used or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A practical reason is as follows.

Typically, you will try out some hyper parameters when optimising losses that are sums over data samples. E.g. the *step rate* of the optimiser (be it plain SGD or something more sophisticated such as Adam) and the number of samples to estimate the gradient, i.e. the *batch size*.

Now, if you do not average, the step rate and the batch size get coupled. E.g. if your update is

$$
\theta_t = \theta_{t-1} - \alpha \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\partial \ell_i}{\partial \theta}
$$

then the step length you do depends on your batch size $N$. Now, if you increase $N$ from say, 16 to 128, you will have to decrease your step rate $\alpha$ by 128/16 in order to keep the magnitude of the update roughly the same.